# Generic Interface and Class / up casting is not working

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand basic Inheritance and polymorphism concepts. but I'm stuck in one scenario.

Consider the following code:

Interface:-

```
public interface IObject<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

Implementation:-

```
public class MyObject<T> : IObject<T>
{
    private T value;

    public MyObject(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T Value => value;
}

public class SquareObject : MyObject<Square>
    {
        public SquareObject(Square square) : base(square)
        {

        }
    }
```

Helper Classes And Interface:-

```
public interface IShape
{

}

public abstract class Shape : IShape
{
    public abstract int Area();
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    int length;

    public Square(int len)
    {
        length = len;
    }

    public override int Area()
    {
        return length * length;
    }
}
```

My question is when I do up casting of square object to shape, it's working fine.

```
IShape shape = new Square(5);
```

But when I do the same using MyObject generic class, it doesn't work.

```
var square = new Square(5);
IObject<IShape> gShape = new MyObject<Square>(square);
```

It says "Cannot implicitly convert type `MyObject<Square>` to `IObject<IShape>`". May be, I can fix it using casting. Can it be possible without casting?

Similarly, I'm also not able to do the same using `SquareObject` class.

```
var square = new Square(5);
IObject<IShape> shapeObj = new SquareObject(square);
```

It says "Cannot implicitly convert type `SquareObject` to `IObject<IShape>`". May be, I can fix it using casting. Can it be possible without casting?

Answer (score 4):

You could declare your `IObject` interface as covariant using

```
public interface IObject<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

Covariant means that you can assign an object implementing `IObject<Derived>` to a variable of type `IObject<Base>`. The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

---

Without explicitly specifying covariance your `MyObject<Square>` is an `IObject<Square>`, but it can't be assigned to a variable of type `IObject<IShape>`.

Comment: Great answer, upvote. also a head slap moment for me

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works like a charm... :)

Comment: Note that it will work because you only have the generic paramater in output positions (property with getter, method return type). The second your interface has the generic parameter  in an input position (property has a setter, method parameter) this will no longer be possible.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes, and it's a good thing because then it would no longer make sense, like assigning a `Cat` to an `IObject<Animal>.Value` which was created as `MyObject<Fish>`.

Comment: @Dirk I know, and I know that *you* know. I was calling it out for the OP :)